# Passenger module not loading in redmine 3.2 installation on centos7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, passenger, redmine

Referred the link `http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=redmine` to install and
Used following commands to install passenger:

```
gem install passenger --no-rdoc --no-ri 
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

It says "Passenger-5.0.16 successfully installed". Then, I try to load the passenger module in passenger.conf, with following:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.0/gems/passenger-5.0.16/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so

PassengerRoot /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.0/gems/passenger-5.0.16
```

When I navigate to the /usr/lib64/ruby directory, I don't find gems folder and then subsequently other folders also don't exist. Because of this, when i give the url in the browser, it opens the folder structure, not the redmine user interface.

Why is this happening. Is there anything I missed. Please suggest.

Comment: At the end of the output of the `passenger-install-apache2-module` command, you'll see the exact config statements (and the correct files) you have to use in your Apache config file. The paths can differ depending on your Ruby version and how you installed it.

Comment: That gives me the path of PassengerRuby, which is fine, but i need the correct path for LoadModule and PassengerRoot, which is the bottleneck. How do i know these paths?